# RadAjaxManager Destroys My Design And Move My Controls (In Preview Mode) that are Inside It

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, radajaxmanager

why radajax manager do this to me ?

plz see these pictures beloaw...

http://www.2shared.com/file/12426877/11c38fb4/WithOut_RadAjaxManager.html

http://www.2shared.com/file/12426799/63a4c800/With_RadAjaxManager.html

this problem exists about every control inside radajaxmanager

i mean radajaxmanager displaces my controls...

how can i fix this?

thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was about inline and block level elements -> we should set the below property of `RadAjaxManager` to inline :

```
UpdatePanelsRenderMode="Inline"
```